# Nginx proxy_pass only works with trailing slash

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite, proxypass

I'm trying to host a [Shiny server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/) on the /shiny/ subpath of my website. Using the config below I can reach my demo app via www.example.com/shiny/demo/.

However, when I exclude the last slash from the URI I end up at www.example.com/demo/ instead, which does not exist. I do not know which part of my config leads to this redirect: although I have `rewrite_log on` I see nothing in error.log. If I remove the rewrite or drop the trailing slash from the proxy_pass everything stops working. The trailing slash in the location directive is not strictly needed (I think?) but I would rather keep it in, removing it seems to make no difference either. I am not sure if I need the proxy_redirect, but removing it does not fix the issue.

Any suggestions on how I can fix my configuration so that the redirect from /shiny/demo to /demo/ goes to /shiny/demo/ instead?

My config, with the relevant location at the bottom:

```
# Redirect to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# Redirect to www subdomain
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;       

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# Main server
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /path/to/root;

    index index.php;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;


    location / {
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
        try_files $uri /$uri $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 302 /$1$is_args$query_string;  }
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }


    location ^~ /shiny/ {
        rewrite_log on;
        rewrite ^/shiny/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:1234/ $scheme://$server_name/shiny/;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `curl -I https://www.example.com/shiny/demo` and check the value of the `Location:` response header and check if it matches your `proxy_redirect` rule.

Comment: You're right, it is the Shiny server that is redirecting, not Nginx. When I query `example.com/shiny/demo` I get redirected to `https://example.com/shiny/demo`, then `https://www.example.com/shiny/demo`. This gets proxied to the Shiny server, which responds with `301 Location: /demo/`. Is there any way to catch this in Nginx?

Comment: Just too late to edit the above... It appears that `proxy_redirect /  $scheme://$server_name/shiny/` does what I need. Is this safe/valid?

Comment: That should work. I don't think you need the `$scheme` or `$server_name`, [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) suggests that they will be added automatically. So the simplest statement would be `proxy_redirect / /shiny/;`