# Nginx proxypass to app folder's subfolder works only with trailing slash

Tags: nginx, proxypass

There is a [partially related question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/971170/nginx-proxy-pass-only-works-with-trailing-slash) but it doesn't help me.

For `site.com` I have

```
location /sub/ {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/ ;
}
```

The 192.168.1.1 IP has a VM with an Apache server on it.

Now when I go to either `site.com/sub` or `site.com/sub/`, it works fine as expected.

But when I go to `site.com/sub/sub1`, it redirects to `192.168.1.1/sub1/` whereas `site.com/sub/sub1/` (with trailing slash) works as expected.

Using a `proxy_redirect` doesn't seem to make a difference. I also tried using with a regex but to no avail.

```
location ~/sub/?(.*)$ {
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/$1 ;
    }
```

Setting the header `Host` just redirects to `site.com/sub1/`.

Nginx logs show a 301 redirect.

I can easily solve the problem by simply creating a new location block for /sub/sub1/ but I would really like to be able to handle it in the same block.

As `site.com/sub/sub1/` with the trailing slash already works fine, how can I get `site.com/sub/sub1` to work correctly instead of redirecting to `192.168.1.1/sub1`? What am I missing here?

Comment: Use `curl -I` to see the exact value of the `Location` header in the HTTP response.

Comment: that's http :// example.com/sub1/   (added spaces to show the complete path)

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for the tip. I think I fixed my problem. But would you also be kind enough to explain a bit what was actually going on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have solved the problem by using a `proxy_redirect`. What I had tried first (when posting the question) was a proxy redirect for

```
proxy_redirect https://example.com/ https://example.com/sub
```

What worked was

```
proxy_redirect http://example.com/ http://example.com/sub
```

I got to the answer by carefully examining the nginx logs and the curl -I output